# How to install scrapyd on freeBSD

Tags: python, scrapy, freebsd, scrapyd

I am trying to install scrapyd on freeBSD but, I am getting this error:

```
$ cd /usr/ports/www/py-scrapyd/ && sudo make install clean
-bash: cd: /usr/ports/www/py-scrapyd/: No such file or directory
```

I have installed scrapy using this command :

```
$ cd /usr/ports/www/py-scrapy/ && sudo make install clean
```

can anyone tell me how to install scrapyd on freeBSD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error implies that `/usr/ports/www/py-scrapyd` does not exist on your system, so you can create it with

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/ports/www/py-scrapyd
```

However, trying to run `make install` in a directory that doesn't even exist is pointless - where did you unpack your ports package (hint, try running `make` there).